# Magento - keep querystring intact after adding to cart

Tags: magento

I have the shop configured to stay on the product page after adding to cart. I need to be able to keep the querystring intact when the page reloads, any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't think this is the way. I would write an event-observer for adding things to the cart (add_to_cart_after) and write the informations you need to the session.